# Upgrading pre-release version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I wanted to test a number of ideas and programs as early as possible on Ubuntu 18.04 server in preparation for a possible upgrade of a number of systems from Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS.

My question is if an early version of Ubuntu 18.04 (dec 2017), fully upgraded e.g. once / week will be equivalent to the official version released in april -18?
If so, I might use the upgraded 18.04 copy as a template for my servers, saving some time and testing.

Comment: For a productive system, I recommend not rushing anything. Start testing 18.04 on a separate machine once it is officially released in April. Do not consider upgrading your productive system before 18.04.1. By default, the `do-release-upgrade` tool will not offer the upgrade before the first point-release is out anyway.

Comment: @bytecommander, the point about waiting for the 18.04.1 upgrade is good, will do that.